# Renaming Variable Output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script to monitor URLs. I've managed to get the information I want, and my script looks like this

```
$logfile = "C:\LogFileTest.log"
Function WriteHeader-Websites {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [string]$URL
    )
    if ($logfile -eq "nologfile"){
        write-host 
        write-host "$URL"
        write-host
    }
    else {
        add-content -path $logfile -value ""
        add-content -path $logfile -value "$URL"
        add-content -path $logfile -value ""
    }
}

Function Test-Websites {
$URLs = Get-Content -Path C:\WebsiteChecks.txt
foreach ($URL in $URLs) {
$ArrayLine =$Line.split(",")
    $
    $Line.name = 
    try {
        $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URL)
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        WriteHeader-Websites "$URL is available!"   
    } catch {
        WriteHeader-Websites ("$URL failed! The error message was '{0}'." -f $_)
    } finally {
            if ($response) {
                $response.Close()
                Remove-Variable response
            }
        }
    }
}

Test-Websites
```

My text file looks like this:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.bing.com
http://www.bbc.co.uk
```

And the output from the script looks like this:

```
http://www.google.com is available!
```

I'd like to be able to add a short name for the websites in the text file, so it uses that name instead.

An example of the text file would be:

```
http://www.google.com,Google Website
http://www.bing.com,Bing Website
```

and I'd like the return to look like:

```
Google Website is available!
Bing Website is available!
```

or

```
Google Website failed! Error message is...
```

But I have no idea how to do that, or what I'd even Google for to find it out. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a csv with headers, then you can refer to the columns using their headers.

```
url,description
http://www.google.com,Google Website
http://www.bing.com,Bing Website
```

Then use [Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) to import the file, so you could do something like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\WebsiteChecks.txt | % {
  $_.description
  $_.url
}
```

---

**Update**
Here's your code rewritten using [Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx) notice I put description in it's own variable as $_ would be updated by the exception in your catch statement.

```
$logfile = "C:\LogFileTest.log"

Function WriteHeader-Websites {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param (
        [string]$URL
    )
    if ($logfile -eq "nologfile"){
        write-host 
        write-host "$URL"
        write-host
    }
    else {
        add-content -path $logfile -value ""
        add-content -path $logfile -value "$URL"
        add-content -path $logfile -value ""
    }
}

Function Test-Websites {

    Import-Csv -Path C:\WebsiteChecks.txt | % {

    $url = $_.url
    $description = $_.description

    try {
        $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
        $response = $request.GetResponse()
        WriteHeader-Websites "$description is available!"   
    } catch {
        WriteHeader-Websites ("$description failed! The error message was '{0}'." -f $_)
    } finally {
            if ($response) {
                $response.Close()
                Remove-Variable response
            }
        }
    }
}

Test-Websites
```

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for your input. I'm fairly new to all this, so I'm not sure how to actually edit my script to make that work? Apologies.

Comment: You don't actually need to include the headers in the CSV file. You can use custom ones with the `-Header` argument to `Import-Csv`.

Comment: Hi David. That worked great! Only thing I had to change was a closing bracket, and the csv file to end in .csv, rather than .txt. Thanks again!